# How should my data to apply of technique time-lagged independent component analysis (TICA)?

Tags: python, concatenation, pca, dimensionality-reduction, molecule

I am trying to apply TICA to reduce dimensions to some data:

```
reader = pyemma.coordinates.source(files, top=pdb) 

reader.featurizer.add_backbone_torsions(periodic=False) (add feature)

tica = pyemma.coordinates.tica(reader) (perform tica on feature space)
```

however I get an error and the following legend.

> RuntimeError: XTC read error: Compressed 3d coordinate

What would be the reason? please any suggestion

I have been reproducing some notebooks following the indications, I would expect my code to work just loading my data, but that error results.